# is_author(get_current_user_id()) returns false when author id and user id match

Tags: functions, user-meta

Inside the loop, when logged in to a localhost test site as `$user->ID == 1` the function `is_author(get_current_user_id())` returns `false` when `get_the_author_meta('ID')` returns 1. Thus, the following conditional is never executed (`is_user_logged_in()` returns `true`):

```
if( is_user_logged_in() && is_author(get_current_user_id()) ) {
    // do stuff
}
```

Have I missed something obvious?

Comment: What are you trying to do with that [`is_author()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_author/)? It would return true only on author archives, e.g. `example.com/author/admin`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you sure you're doing it within the loop? The `is_author` function checks if `$wp_query` is set.

Another option would be to try this:

```
$current_user = wp_get_current_user();

if (is_user_logged_in() && $current_user->ID == $post->post_author)  {
    // do stuff
}
```

Comment: That is pretty much what I ended up doing. 
`if( is_user_logged_in() && (get_current_user_id()===get_the_author_meta( 'ID')) )`

Comment: @MatthewBrownakaLordMatt does this answer your question? If so consider marking it as the accepted answer

Answer (score 0):

another issue might be if you are inside a WP REST API request and did not pass the X-WP-nonce header